# Form 'SELECT' element returning incorrect value

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I have a form select element as follows:

```
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="1" label="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="2" label="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="3" label="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

When I submit the form, and check the $_POST, I get:

array('color' => 'Red')

Where it should be:

array('color' => '1')

I am a little confused, would it have something to do with the label attribute?

---- Edit ----

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dojo.forEach(zendDijits, function(info) {
        var n = dojo.byId(info.id);
        if (null != n) {
            dojo.attr(n, dojo.mixin({ id: info.id }, info.params));
        }
    });
    dojo.parser.parse();
});
var zendDijits = [{"id":"color","params":{"autocomplete":"true","required":"true","dojoType":"dijit.form.ComboBox"}},...
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using just that select code in a simple form...

Comment: Are you sure you're not resetting it somewhere, or have same named input, or something else? Could you provide us by all code...

Comment: Not just PHP, all html form, cause you can replace POST value by value in another same-named input.

Comment: Try removing the `label` attributes.

Comment: Ah ha, the modification comment was what tipped me off.  I copied the code I thought was relevant, however I forgot the part that this is a dijit enabled form element (edit explains better).  I am going to go back to the docs and find the piece I missed here.
P.S --> the form is actually being generated as a Zend_Dojo_Form.

Comment: Found this in the Zend_Framework documentation:

"ComboBoxes return the label values, and not the option values, which can lead to a disconnect in expectations. For this reason, ComboBoxes do not auto-register an InArray validator (though FilteringSelects do)."

That explains my situation, hence why my question was "unanswerable".  Thanks for the mention of 'resetting' it somewhere, that was the tip I needed!

Comment: The solution: change the element from a Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_ComboBox to a Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect... Now returns the correct value to $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the information was not provided in the question for anyone to answer, the solution to the problem was this:

The form element was being created in Zend Framework as a Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_ComboBox, and I found the following information in the documentation.:

> ComboBoxes return the label values, and not the option values, which
>   can lead to a disconnect in expectations. For this reason, ComboBoxes
>   do not auto-register an InArray validator (though FilteringSelects
>   do).

Changed the element to a Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect, and the problem was resolved, working fine now.

Thanks to @devdRew who asked the right question that tipped me off on the thought of dojo/dijit changing the value of what is posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be valid, but the label may be interfering with something. Since you don't need it (you use the same text as the text between the option tags), I suggest you remove it.

Try it this way:

```
<select name="color" id="color">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Green</option>
  <option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Some [more info on the `label` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp).

> ### Definition and Usage
>
> The label attribute specifies a shorter version of an option.
>
> The shorter version will be displayed in the drop-down list.